# Which norm does pseudo-inverse for least square for matrix equation minimizes?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, pseudoinverse

$$AX = B$$

where $A$, $X$, $B$ are general matrices with compatible dimensions. Does

$$\hat{X} := A^+ B$$

minimize $\| AX - B \|_2$ or $\| AX-B \|_F$? Or both?

Answer (score 3):

It minimizes the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Thanks. I just realize I had your book on my shelf.